Modeling filigree type of geometry
I am trying to understand what would be the best way to model such filigree type of geometry:


There are many tutorials how to make such ornaments on flat surfaces but I am struggling to find a good way to model it on any type of more complex 3d objects. What would be the best technic and tools?

Why did you remove the image? My answer was aimed at that.

Hi, its back now

There is really nothing preventing you from modelling this on any surface, it's just a whole lot of work.
You could model a simple surface then work from there, maybe sculpt or if you choose traditional modelling, painting a texture or using some existing pattern texture might be helpful as reference. Changing the topology with something like a knife tool or inserting sliding and connecting vertices and then extruding could work.
You could just use techniques similar to retopology to snap new geometry to existing reference making topology follow along your desired patterns and then extrude detail in various ways.
It's also possible to flatten a surface according to its UV map using Python scripts, Geometry Nodes or add-ons like TexTools to get a shape key that transforms the mesh from flat UV representation to 3d. You can then model anything around the flat surface and use the flat surface to deform your geometry with Surface Deform modifier, then if you deform the original mesh into 3d again your geometry will deform to 3d sticking to that surface as well. Some add-ons may have functions to make this easier., but they are not really needed to do it. That might in some cases be helpful, but might as well be too much trouble for this. You would still need to use various modelling techniques to join parts of the patterns together.

Thank you for detailed explanation
